# Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Context.RootService.ExceptionLocation returns null

Tags: null, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

We have just installed BizTalk 2013 R2 live environment. The live system has 2 active-active cluster BizTalk servers and 2 active-passive SQL cluster servers. In our previous live system, we have one BizTalk server 2010 and one SQL server (no cluster). In previous BizTalk 2010 live system we have a code block to get the current shape name and everything was OK.

```
Context.RootService.FriendlyNameFromShapeId(Context.RootService.ExceptionLocation.ShapeID)
```

But when we migrate this code to new BizTalk 2013 cluster environment, ExceptionLocation returns NULL and we get object reference exception.

Any ideas? Is it related with BizTalk 2013 R2 bug or related with clustering?

Comment: Have you tried it out in a non clustered BizTalk 2013 R2 dev server to see if it works as expected there?

Comment: Yes, i tried it in BizTalk 2013 R2 standalone (single Biztalk and sql server both on same machine) dev machine. The results are the same. The situation is not related with clustering. It is all related with GlobalTrackingOption value in Biztalk DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found the solution after deep analysis. The problem is that, in BiztalkMgmtDb in adm_Group table, the value of GlobalTrackingOption column is 0. Thats why ExceptionLocation object has null value. When we turned this value to 1 (In biztalk setup, the default value of this column is 1), everyting is OK. On the other hand, we will analyze the performance problems of turning this column to 1.